# Entering data into edit text from the beginning

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have fixed height and width of the edit text. 
When i start typing the cursor will be in the middle.
I want cursor to be from the beginning of the edit text.
How i can achieve this?
My code for edit text is as follows

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp" 
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"               
        android:maxLength="100"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set the gravity of the view (where the contents should be aligned).

```
android:gravity="left|top"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested ur code and its working very fine....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
       android:layout_width="230dp"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:maxLength="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

no need of gravity....

Answer (score 1):

hiiiii user1203673

you can do this like fix width only but dont fix height soyr cursor vill be get posotion from starting man 
try this